# JS | Receiving NaN as output when trying to pull content from text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and having trouble parseing text input into a calculation function. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong as I know the actual parse method is correct. I've been trying a bunch of different things but am kind of running around in circles at this point. I'm just making a simple celius/farenheit converter. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**NOTE** I'm trying to use pure JS only

```html
<body>
    <h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
    <form>
        <input id="degrees" type="text" size="5">
        <input type="radio" value="celsius" name="one" id="celsius">Celsius
        <input type="radio" value="farenheit" name="one" id="farenheit">Farenheit
        <button id="equals" type="button">=</button>
        <output id="output">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
var val = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#degrees").value);
var output = document.getElementById("output");


window.addEventListener("load", main);

function main() {
    // listen for a click on the "equals" button
    document.querySelector("#equals").addEventListener(
        "click", function(){convert("val");}); 
}

function convert(val) {
    var c = document.getElementById("celsius");
    var f = document.getElementById("farenheit");

    if (c.checked) {
        toFarenheit(val);
        console.log("celsius selected");

    } else if (f.checked) {
        toCelsius(val);
        console.log("farenheit selected");

    } else {
        console.log("Select whether input is in celsius or farenheit.");
    }
}


function toCelsius(val) {

    output.value = (val - 32) / 1.8;
    console.log(output.value);
}

function toFarenheit(val) {

    output.value = val * 1.8 + 32;
    console.log(output.value);
}
```

Comment: you set `val` at the top of the code when the input element will be blank ... that's NaN .... you never set `val` to any other value ... `var val = someDomElement.value` does NOT automatically update `val` when the input changes

Answer (score 0):

At this point

```
convert("val");
```

you give your `convert()` function the strings `"val"` to be used for conversion and not the variable. This leads to the `NaN` value in the computation later on.

You should move the line, where you retrieve the value `val` to inside the `convert()` function, so it will get updated upon the click. Currently you read the value just at startup (where it will most probably be empty) and never update it.

```
function convert() {
    var c = document.getElementById("celsius");
    var f = document.getElementById("farenheit");
    var val = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#degrees").value);

    if (c.checked) {
        toFarenheit(val);
        console.log("celsius selected");

    } else if (f.checked) {
        toCelsius(val);
        console.log("farenheit selected");

    } else {
        console.log("Select whether input is in celsius or farenheit.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is error

```
     document.querySelector("#equals").addEventListener(
    "click", function(){convert("val");});
```

Nedd

```
     document.querySelector("#equals").addEventListener(
    "click", function(){convert(val);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yip the first commenter to your answer was on the nose. You need to update your `val` variable on click. You can declare it up top and then update it in the function call, or just create it as a scoped variable in the click listener.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6s5nx7dn/